# Referencing gradle properties in application.yml

Tags: gradle, properties, reference, resolution

If this question has been asked and answered, or that there is doc or an example, please forgive me.  I have spent several hours looking for a solution here on stackoverflow and even more time in the gradle doc and haven't been able to make this work.

I have a spring boot project with a pretty standard maven layout.  I am using gradle 2.4.  here's the layout of the relevent files:

```
/gradle.properties
/build.gradle
/settings.gradle
/src/main/resources/application.yml
```

In `gradle.properties`, I have defined the following properties:

```
name=Sample microservice
description=brief description of the service goes here
version=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

In my application.yml file, I'd like to set corresponding spring properties to those same values. (I'd like to define them together in one place and use them in several places.  Since `version` is typically defined in gradle.properties, I want to cluster the rest there as well.)

I've tried the following line in application.yml, but things aren't working as hoped:

```
info.app.name: ${name}
info.app.description: ${description}
info.app.version: ${version}
```

(I also tried `${project.name}`, etc.  That didn't work either.)

I ran `gradlew properties`... the properties are listed with values as expected.  However, when I run a build, the yaml file is copied into `\build\resources\main` as expected, but the `${value}` tokens are not resolved.

I also included the following lines in `build.gradle` file, but things remain unresolved.

```
processResources {
   filesMatching('gradle.properties') { expand(project.properties) }
}
```

(My goal is to use the actuator `/info` endpoint to provide the values of those properties to a service caller.)

Any suggestions or pointers to documentation that help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I recently faced same situation - here is what worked for me.

**TL;DR: In Spring Boot 1.2.5, info.* properties in application.yml are ignored by /info; need to use application.properties for info.* properties.**

First, create src/main/resources/application.properties with this content:

```
info.build.description=${description}
info.build.name=${name}
info.build.version=${version}
```

Second, add this snippet to your build.gradle file:

```
processResources {
    filesMatching("**/application.properties") {
        expand( project.properties )
    }
}
```

Next, run your build as normal. This will process the application.properties file and replace the variables with their build-time values as it copies the file to build/resources/main/application.properties .

For me, when running the deployed .jar, my /info endpoint is populated with the expanded values, which is the goal.

Note that for bonus points you can add this to your build.gradle to get Git info in the /info endpoint, too:

```
apply plugin: "com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties"
```

You will also need to add this to the dependencies section of build.gradle, for that to work:

```
classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties:gradle-git-properties:1.+'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great answer thanks, for those using build.gradle.kts, the code will be : tasks.processResources { filesMatching("**/application.properties") { expand(project.properties) } }

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about using the Copy task? There you can define variables to expand:

application.yml:

```
info.app.name: ${project.name}
info.app.description: ${project.description}
info.app.version: ${project.version}
info.app.foo: ${foo}
```

build.gradle:

```
task copyConfig(type: Copy) {
  from ('src/main/resources') 
  into 'build/config'

  // refer to project and replace foo by string bar
  expand(project: project, foo: 'bar')

}
```

If you want to keep your properties seperated you can also refer to a properties file:

```
expand(project.properties)
```

You might want to take a look at the gradle doc: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html

Did you get the idea?

Comment: This isn't working for me...  I am getting an exception:  Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: project for class: SimpleTemplateScript1

Comment: @drhender could you please provide the entire call stack and/or the build-script

Answer (score 0):

After more tinkering, I discovered that the values are expanded at runtime.  When Spring defines the properties in the environment the ${value} tokens are expanded the way I had hoped.  After more thought, this makes perfect sense.  Those values can't be resolved at build-time because that can be set in a variety of places.  The runtime spring properties reflect the current value, whether the property is set via application.yml in  the jar, application.yml sitting along side the jar, or via a -d switch when the jar is executed.

Comment: Just to clarify, the properties *can* be set at build time - *and* they can be overridden at run time, as you mention. It is still useful to embed build time information into the app so it can be recognized and distinguished *even if this information may be overridden (hidden) later*.